# How to fix the error : Cannot call the requested method (GetBasicPropertiesAsync). A previous call to this method is pending

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, async-await

I am using this `GetBasicPropertiesAsync` method to fetch file properties one by one in a loop.
But I land up with this error:

> WinRT Information :  Cannot call the requested method
>   (GetBasicPropertiesAsync). A previous call to this method is pending
>   and must return before the method can be called again.

My main function has the following code to enumerate all files and folders from the pictures library.

```
List<BaseStorage> listOfFiles = new List<BaseStorage>();
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> foldersList = await curFolder.MCMFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

// For each folder found ...
foreach (StorageFolder folder in foldersList)
{
    listOfFiles.Add(new Folder(folder, parents));
}

// Enumerate all files in the Pictures library.
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await curFolder.MCMFolder.GetFilesAsync();
// For each file found ...
foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
{
    listOfFiles.Add(new Document(file));
}

return listOfFiles;
```

Folder and Document class inherits BaseStorage Class.

```
class BaseStorage
{
    public BaseStorage(IStorageItem storageItem)
    {

        this.Name = storageItem.Name;
        this.CreationDate = storageItem.DateCreated.ToString();

        setModifiedDateAndOwner(storageItem);
    }

    private async void setModifiedDateAndOwner(IStorageItem storageItem)
    {

        // await Task.Delay(500);

        Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<BasicProperties> basicPropsTask = storageItem.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();

        BasicProperties _basicProps = await storageItem.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();

        this.ModifiedDate = _basicProps.DateModified.ToString();

        string fileOwnerProperty = "System.FileOwner";
        List<string> propertiesToFetch = new List<string>();
        propertiesToFetch.Add(fileOwnerProperty);

        IDictionary<string, object> props = await _basicProps.RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertiesToFetch);
        this.Owner = props[fileOwnerProperty].ToString();

        return;
    }
}

class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        setSize();
    }

    private async void setSize()
    {
        BasicProperties _basicProps = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        ulong fileSizeInBytes = _basicProps.Size;
    }
}
```

The problem here is  the method `setModifiedDateAndOwner` has a call to `GetBasicPropertiesAsync` method. Even before this method is complete, the
child class - Document calls `setSize` method which again has a call to `GetBasicPropertiesAsync` method.

This causes the exception to occur. However the behaviour is not very consistent due to threads.

How do I make sure that the method `setModifiedDateAndOwner`  in the Base class is complete before calling the methods in its child class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors can't be `async`, but [there are some ways to work around that](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Since you're using inheritance, you can't use the Factory Pattern from the above article directly, but you can combine the Factory Pattern for the derived class with a version of the The Asynchronous Initialization Pattern for the base class:

```
class BaseStorage
{
    protected BaseStorage(IStorageItem storageItem)
    {
        this.Name = storageItem.Name;
        this.CreationDate = storageItem.DateCreated.ToString();

        Initialization = setModifiedDateAndOwner(storageItem);
    }

    protected Task Initialization { get; private set; }

    private async Task setModifiedDateAndOwner(IStorageItem storageItem)
    {
        …
    }
}

class Document : BaseStorage
{
    private Document(IStorageFile storageFile)
        : base(storageFile)
    { }

    public static async Task<Document> Create(IStorageFile storageFile)
    {
        var result = new Document(storageFile);

        await result.Initialization;

        return result;
    }
}
```

This way, you have to be careful when implementing `Document` and other classes that inherit from `BaseStorage`, but you can only use those classes correctly (you have to `await` the `Task` to get the created instance).